# Visual Studio Command Palette does not exist

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio

I want to use Angular in Visual Studio. I have currently Visual Studio 2017.

I need to install something by using the command palette, but there is not command palette in Visual Studio. I used ctrl+shift+p or ctrl+p combinations, and then nothing happened. I also checked the View section, and there is no integrated command line section or anything else.

Comment: Hey as per my understanding this feature is only available in Visual Studio Code (new editor) not in Visual Studio. You can refer this link to download https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 (The two I use) both have a command palette despite what these answers say. Access it by using CTRL+Q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command pallete only available for Visual Studio Code, https://code.visualstudio.com/. You have installed the wrong one. For Angular development I highly recommend Visual Studio Code, not the full fledged heavy Studio 2017. Please use the link I posted above.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 both have a command palette. It is accessed by using CTRL+Q.

Answer (score 11):

*Visual Studio 2022* has a feature similar to a command palette, called `QuickLauncher`. You can open it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> by default or change the keyboard settings to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, which is what I did for my setup.
([Default Shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#bkmk_tools-popular-shortcuts))

Comment: I'm using 2019 and it also has this feature. Despite the naming being different than other IDEs it does the same thing a command palette does in JetBrains products.

Answer (score 1):

There is **GoTo All(Ctrl + Q)** option in visual studio which has similar features like file search, other interesting features for code navigation, some command execution like **pull, start, run tests** etc.

It's not exactly the one found in Visual Studio Code(Different IDE), its getting pretty close with time.

For example there are many missing like *'start current page application'* which can set in *Tools -> Options -> Keyboard*.

There is a ticket raised for Visual Studio to implement this feature long back and it seems it had been considered by Visual Studio team.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/460947/command-palette.html

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Launch** is Visual Studio's equivalent of the "Command Palette", as seen in other tools like VS Code. A basic 3-minute showcase of this feature is available on Microsoft Learn in its [Visual Studio Time Savers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/vstips/quicklaunch) series since VS 2012.

It appears as an input field in the title bar:

[image: A screenshot of Visual Studio, cropped to an expanded Quick Launch pop-up offering a few recent and sample searches such as "Change hotkeys and keyboard shortcuts", "New Project", and "Theme"]

By default, its shortcut is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, but you can customize the binding for this in at least two different ways:

1. Set a shortcut for the "**Window.QuickLaunch**" command

   - Shortcuts are available in settings, under "Environment > Keyboard"
   - You can also use Quick Launch to jump directly to the shortcut editor, as indicated in the screenshot above, just use "Hotkeys" as a search term
2. If coming from VS Code, you can select "Visual Studio Code" as an additional keyboard mapping scheme

   - When selected, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> focuses the Quick Launch input field for keyboard input, similar to how VS Code pops the Command Palette on top of your active editor
   - The default binding will still apply and be reflected in the placeholder text

Its latest iteration in VS 2022 seems to be more capable than before, now including menu items in its search results. This includes items from extensions, such as "Attach Unity Debugger" from my installation of Visual Studio Tools for Unity (VSTU).